# How are HTML Numbers Calculated in ASCII?

Tags: ascii

I'm attempting to figure out how HTML NUMBERS are calculated in ASCII.

For example, here's code 33:

```
DEC: 33
OCT: 041
HEX: 21
BIN: 00100001
SYMBOL: !
HTML NUMBER: &#33;
```

How does one arrive at the HTML NUMBER being `&#33;` ?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Well, it's the ASCII value (the `dec` value). What exactly is the problem you have?

Comment: @Progman Thank you. Since the `dec` value corresponds to the `33` in the HTML NUMBER, where do the `&` and `#` come from?

Comment: Defined by the HTML standard.

Comment: @Progman would you be able to point me to a web page where I can learn about the relationship between all five characters in an HTML NUMBER and how they're correlated?

Comment: Please check https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/syntax.html#character-references or https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/charset.html#entities